# Let be given $G$ a finite group and $P \in Syl_p(G)$. Give an example of a subgroup $H$ of $G$ where $H \cap P$ is not a Sylow subgroup of $H$.

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Im thinking the order of $H$ and $P$ have to be co-prime, then the intersection is trivial. is that correct?

Comment: Some could take the trivial subgroup as a Sylow $\;p\,-$ subgroup of any group of order not divisible by $\;p\;$ ...

Comment: what about if I take G is cyclic with order p^2, and p-prime. H is subgroup of order p in G. would it work?

Comment: No, it won't, since it is a theorem that if $\;H\lhd G\;$ , then $\;H\cap P\;$ **is** a Sylow $\;p\,-$ subgroup of $\;H\;$ . Thus, you must search for a counterexample with $\;H\le G\;$ *non-normal*

Comment: oh I see. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For another example, take $G:=\text{A}_5$, the group of the $60=2^2 .3. 5$ even permutations of $5$ letters.

For $P$ and $H$ take any two distinct Sylow-5-subgroups. Then $H\cap P=\{1\}$ is not Sylow in $H$.

Answer (score 0):

Take, for example,

$$G=S_4,\,H:=\left\{\,\sigma\in S_4\;/\;\sigma(4)=4\,\right\}\le G\;,\;\;P=\left\langle\,(124)\,\right\rangle=\left\{\,(1),\,(124),\,(142)\,\right\}$$